# How to plot binned data in python with greater than and less than endpoints

Tags: python, matplotlib, binning

I have data with number of counts per trial on x axis and number of trials with given number of counts on the y axis. I wish to bin data on the endpoints so that I have more than 5 trails on the y axis as shown in the image attached.

But how do I achieve this plot (specifically the x axis endpoints) ?

[image]